# Is for_each a global function in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, c++14

Why does using `for_each` as a global function work with GCC?
I would have thought if I did not include the std namespace in my namespace, e.g. `using namespace std;` then all std functions and classes would have to be prefixed with `std::`, but as you can see, `for_each`, `begin`, and `end` are all apparently sitting in the global namespace.

Why?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3 };
    // Shouldn't this need to be std::for_each?
    // And std::begin and std::end??
    for_each(begin(v), end(v), [](auto i){ std::cout << i << std::endl; });
    return 0;
}
```

Command I ran to compile

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)
$ g++ what.cpp
```